# WLS2 UBUNTU: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. and more

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, node-gyp, wsl-2

Trying to npm install a repo i just pulled down and I got the same error as many other people:

`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

So I installed python in my wsl2 instance and restarted my shell, got the same error.
So then i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008864/error-npm-install-g-strongloop-in-ubuntu) and ran

`whereis python`

which outputs this:

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /mnt/c/Python39/python.exe /mnt/c/Python39/python3.dll /mnt/c/Python39/python39.dll /mnt/c/Users/ethan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe /mnt/c/Users/ethan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.exe
```

so i ran

`npm config set python /usr/bin/python3.8`

and now when i try to install again i get a different error

`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.8 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];`

and I have no idea where to go from here because apearently no one else has ever gotten this error

Comment: I also tried ```npm config set python``` with a few of the other items that were listed in the output of ```whereis python``` but none fo them worked either

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here.

But I installed python2.7:

```
sudo apt install python2
```

Then run:

```
npm config set python "/usr/bin/python2.7"
```

This issue solved.

Comment: npm ERR! `python` is not a valid npm option